# Visual Studio don't see header files

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

Welcome

I have 5files in my project

```
main.cpp
ClassOne.cpp
ClasOne.hpp
ClassTwo.cpp
ClassTwo.hpp
```

In .hpp I put defintion of my Class,and in .cpp declarations(of methods,constructors etc.)
I use Header guards in .hpp file,in .cpp include only ClassOne/Two.hpp
Then when I try to compile my code I get errors in .cpp files because these files dont see their .hpp(declarations).
In main file including ClassOne.hpp and ClassTwo.hpp.
What's the reason?
PS I disabled Precompiled Headers

Comment: just one word.. why? Why not definition in cpp and declarations in hpp?

Comment: Without seeing real code and real errors how can we help you?

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to add both the `hpp` files and the `cpp` files to the solution. It's something like `Solution Explorer > Project > Add Existing` and make sure the proper files are included in the project, not just present in the directory.